# Import JSON data for AngularJS Web App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I have been following the Angular tutorials, and I am trying to get my JSON data to appear, yet I know I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out the proper method.

I know that somewhere in my `app.js` my scope is messed up.

How can I display the `Family Name` of each product?

Here is the layout I have:

### app.js

```
var eloApp = angular.module('eloMicrosite', []);

eloApp.controller('homeListController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/Elo/eloMS.min.json')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.products = data;
            });
}]);

eloApp.controller('HomeController', function(){
    this.products = $scope.products;
});
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController as home">
        {{home.products[o]["Family Name"]}}
</div>
```

### JSON Layout

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "Family Name": "3201L",
      "Type": "IDS",
      "Size (inches)": 32,
      "Aspect Ratio": "16:9",
      "Part Number": "E415988",
      "Product Description": "ET3201L-8UWA-0-MT-GY-G",
      "Marketing Description": "3201L 32-inch wide LCD  Monitor",
      "Advance Unit Replacement": "",
      "Elo Elite": "",
      "Package Quantity": 1,
      "Minimum Order Quantity": 1,
      "List Price": 1800
    },
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  "families": [
     {
       category: "Category1"
     },
     {
       category: "Category2"
     }
  ],
  "accessories": [
     {
       category: "Category1"
     },
     {
       category: "Category2"
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The scope in your first controller is not the same as your second controller! Try adding the code in the first controller to the second controller and removing the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `homeListController` on your page instead of `HomeController`, Also need to use `this` instead of using `$scope` as you wanted to follow `controllerAs` syntax, 2nd controller is useless in this scenario, you could remove that from `app.js`.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="homeListController as home">
        {{home.products[0]["Family Name"]}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
eloApp.controller('homeListController', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var home = this;
        $http.get('/Elo/eloMS.min.json')
            .success(function(data) {
                home.products = data.products; //products should mapped here
            });
}]);
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/g3adNAAJokquacCokewQ?p=preview)

Comment: I did that, however I am getting an error - `[$parse:lexerr]` not sure what that means, but I was getting it before as well. Going to do some research on that error, but what could be the cause?

Comment: @Adjit it should be `home.products[0]["Family Name"]` replace `o` with `0`

Comment: Ahh, I am an idiot... not sure why I had a `o` must've been a typo. However, no family name appears with no errors... is my `{{...}}` pointing to the right location?

Comment: @Adjit take a look at updated answer and demo plunkr..will clear out the idea..& where you are wrong, basically you missed to mapped products `home.products = data.products;`

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks, I was pointing to the wrong location for the JSON file, didn't check the console.

Comment: @Adjit Glad to help you..THanks :)